# Docker: Unable to use pythonnet inside a docker image and | Failed to create a default .NET runtime, which would have been "mono" on this system

Tags: python, .net, docker, mono, python.net

I am trying to use `clr` from `Pythonnet` to convert one file type to another using a `.DLL` reference.

This is how my code looks -

```
import clr

clr.AddReference(dll_path)
import RxLibrary

# Convert to ASC Format -----------
input_file = f"./{filename}.rxd"
output_file = f"./{filename}.asc"
RxLibrary.RxLib.ConvertData(input_file, output_file)
```

This is my dockerfile -

```
# Use an official Python runtime as a parent image
FROM python:3.9-slim

# Set the working directory to /app
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the current directory contents into the container at /app
COPY . /app

# Install any needed packages specified in requirements.txt
RUN pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org boto3 python-dateutil asammdf pytz pythonnet

# Make port 80 available to the world outside this container
EXPOSE 80

# Define environment variable
ENV NAME World

# Run test3.py when the container launches
CMD ["python", "./test3.py"]
```

This is the error I get -

```
RuntimeError: Failed to create a default .NET runtime, which would
                    have been "mono" on this system. Either install a
                    compatible runtime or configure it explicitly via
                    `set_runtime` or the `PYTHONNET_*` environment variables
                    (see set_runtime_from_env).
```

I tried using this from one of the SO answers --

```
from pythonnet import load
load('coreclr')
import clr
```

but I get the error as -

```
RuntimeError: Failed to create a .NET runtime (coreclr) using the
                parameters {}.
```

I have tried multiple answers from SO and all over the internet. I still haven't been able to rectify the problem.

Comment: Edit your Dockerfile to include steps to install Mono or .NET Core runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Your Docker file has no indication that you actually installed any .NET runtimes.